# how to send files to mobile phone using Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, java

how to send files to mobile phone from pc using Bluetooth. What are the libraries i need to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need JSR-82 implementation library, find a free one here www.javabluetooth.org

> There aren’t many JSR-82 implementations available for the desktop environment. Most of them are commercial but I was able to find the open source version from www.javabluetooth.org.

http://www.substanceofcode.com/2008/06/20/sending-files-to-mobile-phone-using-bluetooth-and-obex/

Answer (score 1):

Bluecove http://bluecove.org/ would be annother alternative. I use the "latest" Snapshot and it works well.

Comment: I tried to implement bluecove on android to share file on remote devices via bluetooth.but it fails to load the bluecove nativelibray when i use blucove2.1.0 after sometime when i try blucove_snapshot 2.1.1 it results that it need to load jni Load method. Can you provide me basic steps to achieve these to share an file over bluetooth.

Comment: You can download my code from http://cachecow.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cachecow/de.keithpaterson.cachcow.bluecove/